# Why is curl failing to connect to a Kubernetes pod on exposed 80 port in minikube?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am using minikube in VM-ware workstation 17 player (Ubuntu OS). When I expose my container on  containerPort: 80, I am getting an error "curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.244.0.49 port 80 after 21041 ms: Connection refused". Please help me to resolve my error...

I used
$kubectl get pods -o wide
$curl --ipv4 10.244.0.49:80 (Private ip of pod)
But it is not working.

Comment: have you created a service to expose service hosted in container ?

Comment: what is the local ip of your client, from which you are executing curl command ?

Comment: dont forget to set my answer as solution, if it is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access a service hosted in Minikube without creating a tunnel. You need to keep in mind that Minikube runs within a virtual machine (VM), and its network is separate from your host machine.

You created a Deployment and successfully created NodePort Service.

You need not create a tunnel by following command:

```
minikube service serviceNodePort --url
```

Try to open http://127.0.0.1:TUNNEL_Port into your browser.

Here is the official minikube [Documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/)